# trace 0 implies product of symmetric and skew symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

If $A$ is symmetric and $B$ is skew-symmetric, then

$tr(AB)=0$.

I would like to know if the converse holds true. If not, can you give me an example?

Comment: I would like to know if $tr(C)=0$ implies that a matrix $C$ is a the product of a symmetric matrix $A$ and skew symmetric matrix $B$.

Comment: Take $C=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&0\end{pmatrix}$. Then, $\operatorname{tr}(C)=0$ and the characteristic polynomial is $-x^3+3x+2$. On the other hand, if $C=AB$, then $C^T=-BA$. $AB$ and $BC$ have the same characteristic polynomial. $C$ and $C^T$ have the same characteristic polynomial. Then $-(-x)^3+3(-x)+2=-x^3+3x+2$ would hold as equality between polynomials.

Comment: I am having troubles seeing why $C$ and $BC$ have the same characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Me too. It is because it should be $AB$ and $B\mathbf{A}$, instead of $BC$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Your idea is great! Why don't you convert it into an answer?

Comment: If you could edit your comment then to fix that

Comment: @user1551 Just to annoy people [like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3517149/spectral-properties-of-compact-operators?noredirect=1#comment7233433_3517149) and in general the gang that lurks in [CRUDE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/crude). But feel free to write your own version of it anywhere you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $C$ be any real nonsingular $3\times3$ matrix with a zero trace. Then $C$ is not a product of a square matrix (symmetric or not) and a skew-symmetric matrix, because every $3\times3$ skew-symmetric matrix is singular.